# How to compile Node.JS desktop app?

Tags: node.js, compilation, gruntjs, desktop-application, nw.js

to gain more experience coding and support good projects, I recently got into open source projects and Github. After looking for a project I would like to work on, I found Soundnode (https://github.com/Soundnode/soundnode-app). The project uses NW.js, Node.js and Angular.js.

The question is very fundamental: How do I run the NW.js desktop app from the given files?

I was able to compile the app once, using the bash command `open -n -a nwjs --args "/Users/example/path/app"`. But how do I compile the changes? After changing the index.html file, which is the start for the application, I have to terminate the NW.js app and start it up again (otherwise nothing will happen) and then it opens again the same, unchanged, original app (I changed some html text to see if would load the changed index.html).

Could anyone give me a quick guide how to work with this? What I want to change and everything else I will try to figure out on my own. Just need somebody to give me a head start :)

Best Regards, 
 bbrinx - eager to learn.

Comment: Have you reviewed this doc? https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-run-apps

Comment: Thanks, I did. That's how I found out how to run the app the first time. My problem is that after changing the index.html and compiling again nothing changed. Maybe I have to do something like "grunt watch", so that it recognizes the changes?

Comment: there shouldn't be a difference between manually invoking a grunt task and invoking it via the watch task, but I am saying this without actually peeking at your grunt, it may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

nwjs application works next ways:

- direct load web files from FS or web
- archive files to zip `package.nw`

Check nwjs manual and docs: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/ and https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to compile your app is to use [Web2Exe](https://github.com/jyapayne/Web2Executable). It can compile for Win, Mac, Linux.

You can use browser tools for developing/debugging your application. Set `toolbar` option in `true` in `window` section in `package.json` file to see browser elements in your app.